# Simulating AVX-512 mask instructions

Tags: c++, gcc, sse, avx512

According to the documentation, from `gcc 4.9` on the `AVX-512` instruction set is supported, but I have `gcc 4.8`. I currently have code like this for summing up a block of memory (it's guaranteed to be less than 256 bytes, so no overflow worries):

```
__mm128i sum = _mm_add_epi16(sum, _mm_cvtepu8_epi16(*(__m128i *) &mem));
```

Now, looking through the documentation, if we have, say, four bytes left over, I could use:

```
__mm128i sum = _mm_add_epi16(sum,
                             _mm_mask_cvtepu8_epi16(_mm_set1_epi16(0),
                                                    (__mmask8)_mm_set_epi16(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1),
                                                    *(__m128i *) &mem));
```

(Note, the type of `__mmask8` doesn't seem to be documented anywhere I can find, so I am guessing...)

However, `_mm_mask_cvtepu8_epi16` is an `AVX-512` instruction, so is there a way to duplicate this? I tried:

```
mm_mullo_epi16(_mm_set_epi16(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1),
               _mm_cvtepu8_epi16(*(__m128i *) &mem));
```

However, there was a cache stall so just a direct `for (int i = 0; i < remaining_bytes; i++) sum += mem[i];` gave better performance.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are after. Do you have AVX512 hardware but just not a compiler to support?  Not that the 128b (e.g. `_mm_mask_cvtepu8_epi16`) and 256b mask operations require `AVX-512VL` which KNL does not have.  You want a SSE only solution?

Comment: What's wrong with `for (int i = 0; i < remaining_bytes; i++) sum += mem[i]`?

Comment: @Zboson, yes, I cannot easily upgrade the compiler at this point. There's nothing particularly wrong with the simple `for` loop, but I just wondered if there was a better way, as the actual loop body is a bit more complicated than just summation - I've got a circle and am calculating the relative weights between the (left and right) and (top and bottom) halves.

Comment: What AVX512 hardware do you have? What exactly is your hardware?

Comment: @Zboson I have a Core i7-4810MQ; that would appear not to support AVX512... Therefore I would like to find a relatively efficient way of simulating a masked load.

Comment: @KenY-N: your CPU is a Haswell, which has AVX2, so you can use AVX2 masked loads, e.g. [_mm_maskload_epi32](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=AVX2&text=_mm_maskload_epi32&expand=3274,3274), if that helps ?

Comment: You're summing unsigned bytes, so you should use `_mm_sad_epu8(_mm_load_si128(mem), _mm_setzero_si128)` instead of `pmovzx` + `paddw`).

Answer (score 2):

As I happened to stumble across this question, and it still hasn't gotten an answer, if this is still a problem...

For your example problem, you're on the right track.

- Multiply is a relatively slow operation, so you should avoid the use of `_mm_mullo_epi16`.  Use `_mm_and_si128` instead as bitwise AND is a much faster operation, e.g. `_mm_and_si128(_mm_cvtepu8_epi16(*(__m128i *) &mem), _mm_set_epi32(0, 0, -1, -1))`
- I'm not sure what you mean by a cache stall, but if memory access is a bottleneck, and the compiler won't put the constant for the above into a register, you could use something like `_mm_srli_si128(vector, 8)` which doesn't need any additional registers/memory loads.  A shift may be slower than an AND.
- If it's always 8 bytes, you can use `_mm_move_epi64`
- None of this solves the case if the remaining number isn't a fixed number of elements (e.g. you have `n%16` bytes for some arbitrary `n`).  <s>Note that AVX-512 doesn't really solve it either.</s>  If you need to deal with this case, you could have a table of masks and AND depending on what's remaining, e.g. `_mm_and_si128(vector, masks[n & 0xf])`
- (`_mm_mask_cvtepu8_epi16` only cares about the low half of the vector, so your example is somewhat confusing - that is, you don't need to mask anything because the later elements are completely ignored anway)

On a more generic level, mask operations are really just an embedded `_mm_blend_epi16` (or equivalent).  For zeroing idioms, they can easily be emulated with `_mm_and_si128` / `_mm_andnot_si128`, as shown above.

Comment: AVX512 does kind of solve it.  You can do `__mask32 = (uint32_t)-1UL  >> ((32-bytes_left)&31`, which will compile to an integer shift and a `kmov`.  Of course you can generate a mask in AVX2 as well, using various techniques.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306933/vectorizing-with-unaligned-buffers-using-vmaskmovps-generating-a-mask-from-a-m

Comment: Good point, hadn't thought about that.  Thanks for the correction!