# How I can search for byte in byte[] faster?

Tags: java, optimization

I do simple rownumber calculation in InputStream (calc number of NewLines #10)

```
for (int i = 0; i < readBytes ; i++) {
    if ( b[ i + off ] == 10 ) {                     // New Line (10)
        rowCount++;
    }
}
```

Can I do it faster? Without iteration by one byte?
Probably I am looking for some class which able to use CPU specific instructions (simd/sse).

All code:

```
@Override
public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {

    int readBytes = in.read(b, off, len);

    for (int i = 0; i < readBytes ; i++) {
        hadBytes = true;                                // at least once we read something
        lastByteIsNewLine = false;
        if ( b[ i + off ] == 10 ) {                     // New Line (10)
            rowCount++;
            lastByteIsNewLine = (i == readBytes - 1);   // last byte in buffer was the newline
        }
    }

    if ( hadBytes && readBytes == -1 && ! lastByteIsNewLine ) {   // file is not empty + EOF + last byte was not NewLine
        rowCount++;
    }

    return readBytes;
}
```

Comment: what is `readBytes`? Please post its content

Comment: readBytes == size of byte[]

Comment: Honestly, no.  There is no faster way to do it.  It’s already pretty much the same as it would be in assembly language.

Comment: @VGR Are you saying that the JIT is able to produce a [vectorized version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49741811/1899640) of this that compares 16+ bytes at a time like you could in assembly?

Comment: @thatotherguy: there's a reasonable chance that a good JIT can vectorize this loop.

Comment: @DenisZhuravlev: for Java code, trying to reason about the speed of loops like this is highly unlikely to be usefull, unless you have *in-depth* knowledge of the JVM compiler. Benchmark it (using [best practices, which can be tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) and see if it's quick enough).

Comment: @JoachimSauer I'd upvote an answer showing that HotSpot does this

Comment: @thatotherguy Possibly.  I don’t know if it would use SSE2 instructions;  my expectation was that it would JIT-compile to simple increment and compare instructions.  You’d have to call the method many many times per second to see a difference between the two.  Since an InputStream is involved, I’m pretty sure the I/O will be the bottleneck long before the efficiency of the JIT-produced native code will be.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer  I think you are right. My new bottleneck is already outside of this code.

Answer (score 1):

On my system, just moving the `lastByteIsNewLine` and `hasBytes` parts out of the loop results in a ~10% improvement*:

```
  public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {

    int readBytes = in.read(b, off, len);

    for (int i = 0; i < readBytes ; i++) {
      if ( b[ i + off ] == 10 ) {
        rowCount++;
      }
    }
    hadBytes |= readBytes > 0;
    lastByteIsNewLine = (readBytes > 0 ? b[readBytes+off-1] == 10 : false);

    if ( hadBytes && readBytes == -1 && ! lastByteIsNewLine ) { 
      rowCount++;
    }

    return readBytes;
  }
```

* 6000ms vs 6700ms for 1,000 iterations on 10MB buffers read from a ByteArrayInputStream filled with arbitrary text.

Comment: Once it is set to `true`, `hadBytes` should never be set to `false` (on a subsequent call). Use `hadBytes |= readBytes > 0`.

Answer (score 1):

I started with [that other guy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58242440/3474) improvements, and hoisted the array index calculation and the field access out of the `for` loop.

According to my JMH benchmark, this saved *another* 25%, with "that other guy's" implementation clocking 3.6 ms/op, and this version at 2.7 ms/op. (Here, one operation is reading a ~10 MB `ByteArrayInputStream` with around 5000 lines of random length).

```
public int read(byte[] buffer, int off, int len) throws IOException {
  int n = in.read(buffer, off, len);
  notEmpty |= n > 0;
  int count = notEmpty && n < 0 && !trailingLineFeed ? 1 : 0;
  trailingLineFeed = (n > 0) && buffer[n + off - 1] == '\n';
  for (int max = off + n, idx = off; idx < max;) {
    if (buffer[idx++] == '\n') ++count;
  }
  rowCount += count;
  return n;
}
```

Things that really hurt performance: indexing backward over the array.

Things that don't matter: comparing values with the more readable '\n' instead of 10.

Surprisingly (to me anyway), using only one of these tricks by itself did not seem to improve performance. They only made a difference used together.

Comment: it's actually slightly wrong  `int count = ` should the second line (before trailingLineFeed = )

because the last call (n=-1) corrupts trailingLineFeed and makes it false.

Thank you.

Comment: @DenisZhuravlev I think I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily search in `readBytes` after converting it in String:

```
String stringBytes = new String(readBytes);
```

To get the amount of occurrences:

```
int rowCount = StringUtils.countMatches(stringBytes, "\n");
```

To only know if the `\n` is contained in `readBytes`:

```
boolean newLineFound = stringBytes.contains("\n");
```

Comment: Just tried this. It's 3 times slower.
```
        String stringBytes = new String(b);
        int i = -1;
        while ( i < readBytes ) {
            i = stringBytes.indexOf("\n", i+1);
            if ( i == -1 ) break;
            rowCount ++;
        }
```

Comment: still 3 times slower

        String stringBytes = new String(b);
        rowCount += StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf(stringBytes, "\n");

Comment: I looked inside StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf. It uses String.indexOf which does the same iteration byte by byte.

Answer (score 0):

Well, rather than trying to speed up that one specific portion (which I don't think you can), you can try using a different method. Here's a class which you can use to keep track of the number of rows while reading from an InputStream.

```
public class RowCounter {
    private static final int LF = 10;
    private int rowCount = 0;
    private int lastByte = 0;

    public int getRowCount() {
        return rowCount;
    }

    public void addByte(int b) {
        if (lastByte == LF) {
            rowCount++;
        }
        lastByte = b;
    }

    public void addBytes(byte[] b, int offset, int length) {
        if (length <= 0) return;
        if (lastByte == LF) rowCount++;

        int lastIndex = offset + length - 1;
        for (int i = offset; i < lastIndex; i++) {
            if (b[i] == LF) rowCount++;
        }
        lastByte = b[lastIndex];
    }
}
```

Then when reading an InputStream, you can use it like this.

```
InputStream is = ...;
byte[] b = new byte[...];

int bytesRead;
RowCounter counter = new RowCounter();
while ((bytesRead = is.read(b)) != -1) {
    counter.addBytes(b, 0, bytesRead);
}
int rowCount = counter.getRowCount();
```

or you can easily adapt it to whatever situation you need it for.