# How to avoid the error of AVX2 when the matrix dimension isn't multiples of 4?

Tags: c, gcc, avx, avx2, fma

I made matrix-vector multiplication program using AVX2, FMA in C. I compiled using GCC ver7 with -mfma, -mavx.

However, I got the error "incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed."

I think the error would generate if the matrix dimension isn't multiples of 4.

I know AVX2 use ymm register that can use 4 double precision floating point number. Therefore, I can use AVX2 without error in case the matrix is multiples of 4.

But, here is my question.
How can I use AVX2 efficiently if the matrix isn't multiples of 4 ???

Here is my code.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "time.h"
#include "x86intrin.h"

void mv(double *a,double *b,double *c, int m, int n, int l)
{
    __m256d va,vb,vc;
    int k;
    int i;
    for (k = 0; k < l; k++) {
        vb = _mm256_broadcast_sd(&b[k]);
        for (i = 0; i < m; i+=4) {
            va = _mm256_loadu_pd(&a[m*k+i]);
            vc = _mm256_loadu_pd(&c[i]);
            vc = _mm256_fmadd_pd(vc, va, vb);
            _mm256_storeu_pd( &c[i], vc );
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // set variables
    int m;
    double* a;
    double* b;
    double* c;
    int i;
    int temp=0;
    struct timespec startTime, endTime;

    m=9;
    // main program

    // set vector or matrix
    a=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * m*m);
    b=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * m*1);
    c=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * m*1);

    for (i=0;i<m;i++) {
        a[i]=1;
        b[i]=1;
        c[i]=0.0;
    }
    for (i=m;i<m*m;i++) {
        a[i]=1;
    }

    // check start time
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &startTime);
    mv(a, b, c, m, 1, m);
    // check end time
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &endTime);

    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You load and store vectors of 4 `double`, but your loop condition only checks that the *first* vector element is in-bounds, so you can write outside objects by up to 3x8 = 24 bytes when `m` is not a multiple of 4.

You need something like `i < (m-3)` in main loop, and a cleanup strategy for handling the last partial vector of data.  Vectorizing with SIMD is very much like unrolling: you have to check that it's ok to do multiple future elements in the loop condition.

A scalar cleanup loop works well, but we can do better.  For example, do as many 128-bit vectors as possible after the last full 256-bit vector (i.e. up to 1), before going scalar.

In many cases (e.g. write-only destination) an unaligned vector load that ends at the end of your arrays is very good (when `m>=4`).  It can overlap with your main loop if `m%4 != 0`, but that's fine because your output array doesn't overlap your inputs, so redoing an element as part of a single cleanup is cheaper than branching to avoid it.

But that doesn't work here, because your logic is `c[i+0..3] += ...`, so redoing an element would make it wrong.

```
// cleanup using a 128-bit FMA, then scalar if there's an odd element.
// untested

void mv(double *a,double *b,double *c, int m, int n, int l)
{
   /*  the loop below should actually work for m=1..3, but a separate strategy might be good.
    if (m < 4) {
        // maybe check m >= 2 and use __m128 vectors?
        // or vectorize differently?
    }
   */


    for (int k = 0; k < l; k++) {
        __m256 vb = _mm256_broadcast_sd(&b[k]);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < (m-3); i+=4) {
            __m256d va = _mm256_loadu_pd(&a[m*k+i]);
            __m256d vc = _mm256_loadu_pd(&c[i]);
                    vc = _mm256_fmadd_pd(vc, va, vb);
            _mm256_storeu_pd( &c[i], vc );
        }
        if (i<(m-1)) {
            __m128d lasta = _mm_loadu_pd(&a[m*k+i]);
            __m128d lastc = _mm_loadu_pd(&c[i]);
                    lastc = _mm_fmadd_pd(lastc, va, _mm256_castpd256_pd128(vb));
                _mm_storeu_pd( &c[i], lastc );
            // i+=2;  // last element only checks m odd/even, doesn't use i
        }
        // if (i<m)
        if (m&1) {
            // odd number of elements, do the last non-vector one
            c[m-1] += a[m*k + m-1] * _mm256_cvtsd_f64(vb);
        }

    }
}
```

I haven't looked at exactly how gcc/clang -O3 compile that.  Sometimes compilers try to get too smart with cleanup code (e.g. trying to auto-vectorize scalar cleanup loops).

Other strategies could include doing the last up-to-4 elements with an AVX masked store: you need the same mask for the end of every matrix row, so generating it once and then using it at the end of every row could be good.  See [Vectorizing with unaligned buffers: using VMASKMOVPS: generating a mask from a misalignment count? Or not using that insn at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306933/vectorizing-with-unaligned-buffers-using-vmaskmovps-generating-a-mask-from-a-m).  (To simplify branching, you'd set it up so your main loop only goes to `i < (m-4)`, then you *always* run the cleanup.  In the `m%4 == 0` case, the mask is all-ones so you do the final full vector.)  If you can't safely read past the end of the matrix, you probably need a masked load as well as masked store.

---

You could also look at aligning your rows for efficiency, or a row stride that's separate from the logical length of rows.  (i.e. pad rows out to 32-byte boundaries).  Leaving padding at the end of rows simplifies the cleanup, because you can always do whole vectors that write padding.

---

**Special case `m==2`**: instead of broadcasting one element from `b[]`, you'd like to broadcast 2 elements into two 128-bit lanes of a `__m256d`, so one 256-bit FMA could do 2 rows at once.