# AVX2 vectorization for code similar to prefix sum (decrement by count of preceding matches in short fixed-length arrays)

Tags: simd, avx, bitmask, avx2, prefix-sum

I have some performance-critical code that looks like this:

```
uint8_t v[128], w[128];

for (int i = 0; i < 128; ++i) {
    // ...
    for (int j = 0; j < 128; ++j) {
        // ...
        if (v[j] == w[i]) {
            // ...
            for (int k = j; k < 128; ++k) {
                v[k]--;
            }
            break; // <-- this is critical
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `break` is critical there, not just an early-abort optimization. If I take it out, my tests fail.

I'm trying to speed this code up using AVX2.

I first load `v` to an array of 4 AVX2 registers. The `if (v[j] == w[i])` line is easily replaced by `_mm256_cmpeq_epi8`, broadcasting `w[i]` to all lanes.

By breaking up the `j`-loop into 4 loops of 32 iterations each, I know exactly which element of the AVX2 array I am currently on; assume e.g. a hit on the `if` for some `j` with 32 <= j < 64, which corresponds to the AVX2 array element of index 1. For the innermost (`k`) loop, I thought of using `_mm256_movemask_epi8`, then the `bsf` instruction to extract the lowest set bit (call it `b`), followed by one of the techniques [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488675/is-there-an-inverse-instruction-to-the-movemask-instruction-in-intel-avx2) to do an "inverse `_mm256_movemask_epi8`". Now I can just subtract the result from `v[1]` -- for `v[2]` and `v[3]` I just subtract `_mm256_set1_epi8(1)`.

Another option is to do a [prefix sum](https://en.algorithmica.org/hpc/algorithms/prefix/). Since multiple lanes may match in the comparison, I could do `_mm256_cmpgt_epi8` with zero after the prefix sum.

Although I haven't worked out the details, I intend to avoid the explicit branch (`break` in the innermost loop body) since it's probably cheaper than the inevitable pipeline flush, given that the branches will be completely random.

Still I can't shake the feeling that there must be a simpler solution. For instance, for the "inverse `_mm256_movemask_epi8`" solution, I don't have a general mask, but only 32 possible values out of 2^32: 0x0, 0x1, 0x3, 0x7, 0xF, 0x1F, 0x3F, ..., 0xFFFFFFFF.

Can anyone think of a different, ideally simpler, strategy?

Comment: Can you summarize in words what the point of this code is?  Decrement every element at and above every match? (But not quite that because of the break). Or decrement every element of `v[]` by the number of elements in `w[]` that match any element of `v[]` before or at this element?

Comment: What happens inside the `// ...` parts?

Comment: This is somehow related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77800999/ -- note that once you got a `0x00`/`0xff` mask you can simply add that byte-wise to the `v` array.

Comment: @PeterCordes My problem is basically related to permutation ranking, e.g. see the code [here](https://github.com/mateuszchudyk/lehmer/blob/89b90d63afb3f7fef5525988f3982315288dfc0c/lehmer.py#L56]). I arrived at the version shown in the question after a few transformations.

Comment: @chtz thank you! [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77802924/523079) to the linked question provides an excellent idea (using `_mm256_cmpgt_epi8`) for the "inverse `_mm256_movemask_epi8`" part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### One `w[i]` at a time: find first match and decrement all later `v[j]`

(This strategy didn't end up being very efficient due to the loop-carried dependency in compare/`tzcnt`/generate vectors of 0 or -1/`vpaddb`, even if keeping `v[]` in four __m256i vectors to avoid store/reload. See the OP's comments below.)

Your idea of doing it this way avoids correctness problems with needing to change `v[j]` before comparing, which are a showstopper for most of my earlier ideas.

Yes, with four `vpcmpeqb` / `vpmovmskb` we can get a 128-bit bitmap which we search with tzcnt.  You probably *don't* want to use a `__m128i` load of that to find the first non-zero byte of the 128-bit bitmap, instead just two 64-bit chunks with a `cmov` (C `?:` ternary) to select between `tzcnt_u64(low_half)` + `64 + _tzcnt_u64(high_half)`.  You'll need shift/OR to combine pairs of `uint32_t mask0 = _mm256_movemask_epi8(...)` into `uint64_t mask_low = mask0 | ((uint64_t)mask1<<64);`

Making this fully branchless (or branching the same way every time) would require extending `v[]` to `uint8_t v[128 + 96]` so it's safe to write 3 vectors past the end, so we can just unconditionally do `store( add(load, set1(-1)))` for the 3 vectors after the one containing the first match.

To get a vector that's `-1` at or above a given count, we can load from a sliding window onto an array of `uint8_t maskbuf[] = {0,0,0,0,...,-1,-1,-1,-1}` as in [What is the best way to loop AVX for un-even non-aligned array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74515863/what-is-the-best-way-to-loop-avx-for-un-even-non-aligned-array/74517619#74517619) / [Vectorizing with unaligned buffers: using VMASKMOVPS: generating a mask from a misalignment count? Or not using that insn at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306933/vectorizing-with-unaligned-buffers-using-vmaskmovps-generating-a-mask-from-a-m)

Another option instead of making a vector mask, just do four unaligned vectors starting at the first match, so `uint8_t v[128 + 127]`.  But that will perform terribly, with store-forwarding stalls when our vector loads next iteration don't line up with our stores from this iteration.  (*[What are the costs of failed store-to-load forwarding on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135369/what-are-the-costs-of-failed-store-to-load-forwarding-on-x86/69631247#69631247)*)

---

##### Ideas that don't account for `v[j]` maybe changing before we compare

I wrote the rest of this answer before realizing that a `v[j]` can have changed in one outer iteration before we compare it again next outer iteration.  I'm going to post anyway in case some of these ideas are salvageable)

These are based on the idea that we decrement every element of `v[]` by the number of elements in `w[]` that match any element of `v[]` before or at this element.

Thinking first about how to work between 32-byte chunks, if we can get all elements beyond the first 32, the decrement count for `v[j]` for `j=32..127` due only to the first block is the number of w[0..127] elements that matched any element of `v[0..31]`.

[`pcmpestrm`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pcmpestrm) can do any against any between 16-byte vectors (https://www.strchr.com/strcmp_and_strlen_using_sse_4.2 has a good summary of the things it can do in general, despite the article about strcmp and strlen where these instructions are worse than SSE2, let alone AVX2.)

We can OR together the masks. (Or if 0 doesn't occur in the arrays, `pcmpistrm` can be used, which is significantly faster, 3 uops instead of 9 on Intel / 7 on Zen 4.  https://uops.info/ . Throughput ratios aren't that extreme, like 5c vs. 3c on Intel or 3c vs. 2c on Zen 4, since the extra uops can run on other ports.  But we do have some other work to do in parallel so it's not great.)

`pcmpestrm` might be better than manually brute-force comparing to do every rotation of 16-byte lanes (vpshufb) on normal and swapped copies of a `__m256i`.  Like two chains of `vpshufb` to rotate 16-byte lanes by 1, on a vector from memory and the same vector with 16-byte halves swapped, so most of the shuffles are in-lane.  So you'd be running a lot of `vpshufb` / `vpcmpeqb` / `vpor`.  That can be prefix-summed with some shuffles, but note that `vpsadbw` against `_mm256_setzero_si256()` will hsum every chunk of 8 bytes into the bottom of the qword.

###### Algorithmic improvements, not just brute-force?

(Also not considering that each `v[j]` can be different on different outer iterations.)

**Non-brute-force options** include sort + binary-search, or check a bitmap or bool array if we're considering something as slow as checking every `v[j]` separately against `w[0..127]`.

Or making a histogram, `uint8_t wcounts[256];`, then one-pass prefix-sum (which you use as a decrement count) like `decrement += wcounts[ v[j] ];` `v[j] -= decrement;`.  Histogramming isn't very SIMD-friendly, and it's so short you might not want to use separate arrays of counts to hide store-forwarding latency bottlenecks on repeated elements.  But if you do, SIMD is great for vertically summing `count0[i] += count1[i]`, just 256 bytes to process, worth it if `w[]` often contains a lot of the same value.

But this doesn't work because `v[j]` might have changed by `1` while looking at `w[0]` and now match or not match different elements.

There might still be something useful we can do to reduce the need for SIMD brute-force searching, instead using reverse lookup tables that we update on the fly.  But I'm not seeing anything obvious.

---

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Something I didn't mention in the question is that I already have an implementation of a different algorithm (also O(n^2)) for the same task, and this is an alternative approach I'm investigating. I've implemented your idea and it's considerably slower than that alternative approach, which I suspect is due to the algorithm being latency-bound from comparison -> count trailing zeros -> subtraction. I will investigate the idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77802924/523079) for an "inverse `_mm256_movemask_epi8`" specific to this case.

Comment: @swineone If you leave out essential parts of your algorithm, it is very hard to suggest an optimal solution ...

Comment: @chtz I don't think anything essential was left. As a matter of fact I made sure to trim anything that wasn't essential. I believe the code in the question is the crux of the issue.

Comment: @swineone: Oh yeah, loop-carried latency would be bad for this strategy, even if we keep `v[]` in four `__m256i` variables that stay hot in registers.  It was kind of an afterthought after realizing that each v[j] can change between each outer iteration.  One advantage to branchy code is avoiding data dependencies some of the time.  Branches "only" mispredict about half the time at worst, except in pathological cases, and it's not a fully pipeline nuke: it can start as soon as the branch inputs are ready, so a low latency check can leave other work before the branch still in flight.

Comment: @PeterCordes after analyzing the code for this and my alternative approach using [uiCA](https://uica.uops.info), I have come to the conclusion that this approach is hopeless due to the loop-carried dependencies -- my other approach parallelizes much much better. Of course that's an algorithmic issue, but still, your answer was very helpful in understanding the performance characteristics of this code, and as such I have accepted it.